# float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

[image][image]I'm trying to clean a column of abstract in a dataset

this is the cleaning function I'm using

```
#remove punctuations
def remove_punctuation (text):
    no_punct="".join([c for c in text if c not in string.punctuation])
    return no_punct
```

when I write the line

```
df['abstract'] = df['abstract'].apply(lambda x: remove_punctuation(x))
```

I get: 'float' object is not iterable

When column abstract is of type string.

Can anybody explain why it does not work?

Comment: Quick dirty fix: protect your `remove_punctuation` function by checking the type of `text`. Long term solution: find if some actual `Float` values are sneaking into your columns.

Comment: Because the column is not entirely text.  Isn't the obvious debugging step to print `text` and `type(text)` in your function and see what you get?

Comment: Post the entire traceback message so we can see the failing line. We can't reallly answer because we don't know what your data is. It appears as though "abstract" is a column of floats. You could add `assert isinstance(text, str), f"'{text}' must be a string"` to your function to see if its the string you think.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need the lambda here. `apply` calls the function with a single parameter. Since your lambda doesn't modify that parameter at all, you could just `df['abstract'].apply(remove_punctuation)`.

Comment: @tdelaney I posted the traceback

Comment: @everyone is there a way to convert all elements of pandas dataframe to string ?

Comment: you can convert the whole column to string by: 
`df['abstract'] = df['abstract'].astype(str)` 

or alternately you can update your function to return 
`no_punct="".join([c for c in str(text) if c not in string.punctuation])`

but then values like 10.0 will become 100 after removing the punctuations

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal converting to string worked. Thank you

Comment: As @ShivamAgrawal mentions - the conversion is risky. It may be worth working out why this column is a float in the first place.